# How to return a value from a coroutine that was run with Tornado's IOLoop?

Tags: python, asynchronous, tornado, python-3.5

Let's say I have this asynchronous function (Python 3.5)

```
async def func():
    return '42'
```

I have a Tornado I/O loop and I'm looking for a way to execute it.

```
import tornado.ioloop

ioloop = tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.current()
ioloop.start()
```

I could just use `IOLoop.add_callback(func)`, but I need a return value as well.
Any ideas on what is needed to retrieve the return value from it?

**EDIT**
The `func` coroutine method actually takes a string and sends it to a server, receiving a response, unpacking it appropriately and returning a tuple of data.
It is called from a regular (non-async) method that assembles the string based on its arguments and is supposed to get a response and return the data to a caller.
The IO loop is a class variable (accessible with `self.`)

Here's an example:

```
def register(self, arg1, arg2):
    # process args here

    ret_value = self.ioloop.add_callback(func, arg1, arg2)  
    # The above line is incorrect code, just for the idea

    return ret_value
```

**SECOND EDIT**
This is the part of the code that throws the AssertionError:

```
async def _send(self, arg1):
    self.ws.write_message(arg1)
    resp = await self.ws.read_message()
    return resp

def callback(self, future):
    print('future', future.result())

def register(self, arg1):
    future = self._send(arg1)
    self.ioloop.add_future(future, self.callback)
```

I started the execution of `register` using a PeriodicCallback in the class `__init__` method.
The variable `future` in the `register` method contains a `<coroutine object Client._send at 0xb652c41c>` and the `is_future` check will only pass if what's given as a future is an instance of `concurrent.futures.Future` or `tornado.concurrent.Future`

Answer (score 0):

Two options: make `register` a coroutine, or receive the return value of `func` in a callback.

Option one:

```
async def register(self, arg1, arg2):
    ret_value = await func(arg1, arg2)
    return ret_value
```

Option two:

```
def callback(future):
    try:
        ret_value = future.result()
        # Do something with ret_value here.
    except Exception as exc:
        # Log the exception or something.
        print(exc)

def register(self, arg1, arg2):
    future = func(arg1, arg2)
    self.ioloop.add_future(future, callback)
```

Option two is awkward, obviously, because you cannot use ret_value in the original `register` function. I'd go for option one, make `register` a coroutine. Then the caller of `register` must also be a coroutine, all the way up the call stack.

That's an iron law of async programming: in order to communicate over the network, your function must be a coroutine that executes a `yield` or `await`, or you must register a callback and exit the current function.

Comment: But `run_sync` stops the event loop and that's not exactly what I want. The function `func` in the actual code is supposed to be a regular process, so stopping the event loop is not an option

Comment: Can you give some more context please about your question? How are you calling `func` and what do you want to do with its return value?

Comment: I get an `AssertionError` in the `add_future` method. The line that throws the exception is `assert is_future(future)` and apparently what's returned from the `func` call is not a valid future. Why is that? The complete code that throws an error is in another post edit.  
Also, unfortunately turning all callers into async functions won't be an option for me as it is called from the GUI and that would cause massive code changes